# Aws route53 tcp traffic to ec2 with vpc private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I use aws multi-ec2 with vpc private subnet(without public IP).

I would route traffic with route 53 FQDN to ec2'1 or ec2'2

like

ec2-1.test.com -> ec2'1

ec2-2.test.com -> ec2'2

If only http or https traffic, it will be done by alb with rule.

If TCP, I know to use nlb with ec2 nginx to proxy traffic to ec2'1, and ec2'2.
(but I wouldn't use sni, because not all tcp traffic use tls)

Is there another service that  could do this? (gateway load balance can do this?)

---

I expect use only one public internet access point route tcp traffic through FQDN.

like alb - alb'1

ec2-1.test.com ( set alb dns at route 53) -> alb'1 -> use rule redirect traffic to ec2'1

ec2-2.test.com ( set alb dns at route 53) -> alb'1 -> use rule redirect traffic to ec2'2

Comment: I'm not clear about the reason why nlb can't handle it

Comment: I don't know where or which aws service can  integrate with using only one nlb for routing the traffic ec2-1.test.com to ec2'1,  ec2-2.test.com to ec2'2 (like alb can use rule)